# Edittext text selection with spinner change event

Tags: android

After text selection from edittext I need to choose color from spinner. After selecting color I have to change font color for the selected text. When I click spinner,  Spinner only focused. Edittext selection canceled. How to handle both events?

Comment: you can remember selection positions for example, and when an item of the spinner is selected you can return focus to the edittext, and set back the sellection

Comment: When focus changed selection start and end position also reset to 0.

Comment: yes, that's whi I say that you can remember start and end positions when focus is lost.

Comment: I had used setOnFocusChangeListener  for edittext.But I can't get the focus lost action